# Chirpy theme with jekyll picture is not uploading

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby, jekyll

use the chirpy theme, and i have this problem i opened a new folder named ‘images’, and on my markdown editor I see the picture perfectly, but on my site, i see it like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Kzg0.png)

and its not loading it…
any suggestions?
i tried to put an image from online, it did work but when i click on it it does not pop up nicely as it should (getting biger on the website layout it self, and clicking out side the picture getting you back the the post), it just opens the site that the picture is from…
thank you very much~ i looked on it on the console and i got error '403'.
thank you very much~

What i tried:
i tried to look at the picture in 'inspect' in google chrome, and look at the part of the code for the picture and change it some how in my own code, with no luck.

Comment: are you talking abou the markdown? `---
layout: mypost
title: "Hello world"
date: 2024-01-20 00:00:00 +0800
categories: [testing]
tags: [diving]     
---


# hello world
![cheese pizza](/assets/images/figure1.jpg)
[cheese pizza](/assets/images/figure1.jpg)
` this is my github page oshopythton.github.io

Comment: https://oshopython.github.io/ had a typo

Comment: Yes but if you go inside the other post, you will see shine black thing, which I don't want. And like what I wrote that like I saw on other chripy themes, that the picture should be pop up with shadow behind... That's what I'm trying to achive